# Event correlation in logstash(Need to join two files fields data into single json record)

Tags: join, filter, logstash

I am having log data in the below path

/Download/aaaa/sysOne/one.txt

Error,12345,erredescriptionOne
Error,12345,erredescriptiontwo
Error,12345,erredescriptionthree

and I have one more file /Download/aaa/config/config.txt with below data

AppName,SystemName,DatabaseName
FirstName,sysOne,DBOne
SecondName,systwo,DBTwo
ThirdName,systhree,DBThree
FourthName,sysfour,DBFour

I want to load the data as a single json record in ES from both the files using sysOne value as reference.

I tried with add_field but it is not working

Could you please help me how to proceed on this.

Comment: I'd say that logstash is the wrong tool to do that with files. But if you load all the data from your files in the same database, you could use the jdbc input, with a join in your request.

Comment: Can I get the approach how to do that. Actually I want to push the processed data(Joined/combined) into elastic search toshow into kibana as a single json record

Comment: No you can't. SO is not a coding service, especially if you don't give the impression of having done a minimum of work on your side. Read the SO on what kind of question are acceptable. (Also the logstash doc could be a good idea)

Comment: Sorry for that. I explored about input jdbc but we can't store the data into database as it is real time data and it is continuously coming to that files. Can you please suggest any other approach with ELK.

Comment: It's beyond what I can answer and I think it might be beyond the capabilities of logstash if the two files are updated in real-time; if only one file is updated in real-time, it could work.

Comment: Thank you but both files data are real time only.I have small concern,  I want to know  the possibility of accessing the first grok pattern field value  into second grok pattern.  See the below example.

Comment: filter {

if [type] == "ConfigFileData"
{
   grok{
        match => {"message" => "%{DATA:NameOne},%{DATA:NameTwo},%{DATA:NameThree}$"}
      }
}

if [type] =="System Logs"
{

grok {
  match => {"message" => "%{DATA:NameFour},%{DATA:NameFive},%{DATA:NameSix}$"}
}
}
}

Comment: I want to access the NameOne value from the first grok patten into second grok pattern 

i.e along with NameFour,NameFive,NameSix I want NameOne also in the same pattern.

Comment: Please help me in the above scenario. Thanks for your help in advance